# how to verify a solution to the 3D wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Is $E = (A\sin(k(x-ct)),0,0)$ a solution to the wave equation $c^2 \nabla^2E=\frac{\partial^2E}{\partial t^2}$?
What is $\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}$?

Comment: I am assume the derivative with respect to time?

Additionally: Please provide context to your question and use mathjax for formulas. Finally, you tag seems weird.

Comment: Exactly @maxmilgram...

Answer (score 0):

$\partial E / \partial t = (A(-kc)cos(k(x-ct)),0,0)$ and $\partial^2 E / \partial t^2 = (-Ak^2c^2sin(k(x-ct)),0,0)$.

$\nabla E = (Akcos(k(x-ct)),0,0)$ and $\nabla^2 E = (-Ak^2 sin(k(x-ct)),0,0)$.

The equation is verified, you have a wave equation.

Comment: how about if E=(A,Asin(k[z-ct]),0)

Comment: How about you do the calculation?

Comment: will ∇E=(0,0,0)?

Comment: Yes, it is. $E_y$ is independant of $y$.